# how to pass useState setter and object together to child element in react typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-props

I have problem passing useState setter and object (both together) to the child component.
Object was passed successfully just spreading it like this {...object}, but what is the syntax to pass setter along?
code example:

```
<div>
  {array && array.map((item) => {
     return (
       <div key={item.id}>
          <Component {...item} setMyState={setMyState}/> ///perhaps it's wrong aproach
       </div>
     );
   })}
</div>

///inside child component

interface IProps {
  item: Item; /// of type item, that was imported from other file
  setMyState: ()=> void;
}
function Component(props:IProps) {
///return some elements
}
```

this gives error

```
"(property) IProps.setMyState: () => void Type 'Dispatch<SetStateAction<Item[]>>' is not assignable to type '() => void'"
```

setMyState hook takes entire Item of type Item and filters it so it is quite difficult to me to properly describe what type of data it requires. Entire Item is array of objects

EDIT: according suggestion I have edited code like this:

```
<div>
 {array && array.map((item) => {
    return (
      <div key={item.id}>
         <Component item={item} setMyState={setMyState}/>
      </div>
    );
  })}
</div>

///inside child component

interface IProps {
 item: Item; /// of type item, that was imported from other file
 setMyState: Dispatch<Item[]>;
}
function Component(props:IProps) {
///return some elements
}
```

Now props passes succesfully

Comment: https://www.carlrippon.com/typed-usestate-with-typescript/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as it says in error, you can try specifying

```
setMyState: Dispatch<SetStateAction<Item[]>>
```

Comment: thanks, please specify - I should set this type inside "interface IProps"? because typescript is still unhappy - "type SetStateAction = /*unresolved*/ any"

Comment: yes inside interface IProps, maybe try with only Dispatch type ?

Comment: yes, that is working in the child side, but syntax "<Component {...item} setMyState={setMyState}/>" perhaps is wrong, because now typescript tells "Property 'item' is missing in type '{ setMyState: Dispatch<SetStateAction<Item[]>>; id: number; first_name: string; last_name: string; gender: string; age: number; selected: boolean; }' but required in type 'IProps'."

Comment: try replacing <Component {...item} setMyState={setMyState}/> by <Component item={...item} setMyState={setMyState}/>

Answer (score 0):

change the setMyState type to Dispatch<SetStateAction<Item[]

```
setMyState: Dispatch<SetStateAction<Item[]
```